# Regex problems Java

Tags: java, regex, string

I am trying to match the following pattern in a string and extract it as a substring.

The pattern always follows

`<D-10-helloworld-84>`

The `'D'` can either be `'D'` or `'E'` but nothing else. the message in the middle can have any character and each number is always a digit decimal (`5` would `05` for example).

I have tried the following:

```
String text = "sdsas<D-10-helloworld-84>kjvkjv";

Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("^<[ED]-[0-9]{2}-(.?)-[0-9]{2}>$");
Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(noiseFrame);
String newText = matcher.group(1);
```

But not match is being found. What's happening here? Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since your input has some text before/after `< and >` you need to remove anchors `^ and $` from your regex:

```
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("<[ED]-[0-9]{2}-(.*?)-[0-9]{2}>");
```

Also it seems you haven't called matchers `find()` or `matches()` method which is required before you can call `group()`.

#### Code:

```
String text = "sdsas<D-10-helloworld-84>kjvkjv";

Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("<[ED]-[0-9]{2}-(.*?)-[0-9]{2}>");
Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(noiseFrame);
if (matcher.find()) {
    String newText = matcher.group(1);
    System.out.println(newText);
}
```

Comment: Removed anchors but still no match found.

Comment: check updated now. It seems you have't called `find() or matches()` method yet.

Comment: in this case all that is happening is newText is being set to "helloworld" without the other parts left and right of it :/

Comment: It is because you have brackets around inner most part only `(.*?)` if you want full match you can just use: `String newText = matcher.group(0);`

Comment: The point is not to get the message inside but to get the frame itself all of "<D-10-helloworld-84>" which may appear in a string such as sdsas<D-10-helloworld-84>kjvkjv

Comment: Yes thats it group 0 for match of all pattern :) Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Try the next regular expression:

```
.*<[ED]-[0-9]{2}-([^-]+)-[0-9]{2}>.*
```

e.g.:

```
String text = "sdsas<D-10-helloworld-84>kjvkjv";
String newText = text.replaceAll(".*<[ED]-[0-9]{2}-([^-]+)-[0-9]{2}>.*", "$1");
```

Using a constant:

```
private static final Pattern REGEX_PATTERN = 
        Pattern.compile(".*<[ED]-[0-9]{2}-([^-]+)-[0-9]{2}>.*");

public static void main(String[] args) {
    String input = "sdsas<D-10-helloworld-84>kjvkjv";

    System.out.println(
        REGEX_PATTERN.matcher(input).matches()
    );  // prints "true"

    System.out.println(
        REGEX_PATTERN.matcher(input).replaceFirst("$1")
    );  // prints "helloworld"
}
```